# Where is "struct _clientid_index_hash " declared in mosquitto code base?

Tags: struct, mqtt, mosquitto

I [mosquitto_broker.h](http://git.eclipse.org/c/mosquitto/org.eclipse.mosquitto.git/tree/src/mosquitto_broker.h) there is a 
struct mosquitto_db{

struct _clientid_index_hash *clientid_index_hash;

};

I am not able to figure out the declaration of "struct _clientid_index_hash ".

Answer (score 1):

It is unused, so doesn't actually matter. The pointer to the struct could be removed without any consequence.